# Azure Worker Role Blob backup

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to make a backup of the entire local azure storage content in a container name "backup" using the Worker Role in a Azure Cloud Service Project. My backup should be made like every 10 minutes. Any idea where i should start?

Comment: Please define "local blob storage"

Comment: When i said local blob storage i mean that i work on the local development storage!

Comment: And you want to backup where? To a blob storage in an Azure data center?

Comment: No, i want to backup it in a container name"backup" in my local storage!

Comment: OK.  Edit your question with these two facts.  It will be clearer and you'll have more chances to get an answer.

Comment: Are you using the storage emulator in production? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240580/running-azure-emulators-locally-for-production) stack overflow question summarizes well: "You're not running in Azure with the emulator; your code is executed in local processes with a local standalone database process. You'll have 0 SLA, non-redundant storage, absolutely no visibility into overall system health... It's simply not a production environment." If testing is what you're doing, then carry on -- otherwise take care.

Answer (score 0):

What is local blob storage? Inside the worker role you have no blob storage.

Also use webjobs for scheduling, much simpler.

Azure already has 3 replicas of blob storage.
See this SO post for more info: [What is the best way to backup Azure Blob Storage contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561844/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-azure-blob-storage-contents)

Comment: When i said local blob storage i mean that i work on the local development storage!

Comment: AzCopy can help you, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/#overview